# Import hid OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have installed python and then did install `'pip install hidapi'` and `'pip install hid'`. I tried command,

[image]

Mine is windows7 64bit and i tried pyhton2.7, python3.5 and python3.6 got same error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I cant create one because I need 50 reputation points! In any case, I ran into this problem before with another module. What you need to do is check where that module was installed. Since you have three different python installations 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, my guess is it got installed in the wrong one.

For example, if the python shell you have opened is running from
c:\Python27\python.exe (which is what it looks like) then you need to make sure the "hid" and "hidapi" modules are in the C:\Python27\Lib directory. If they are not in there, then you will see that error.  So you should try to find those modules on your computer, and then copy them to the C:\Python27\Lib directory. If you cannot find them, then maybe an error occurred when you tried installing them. If that's the case, then you will need to find out what is causing it, and fix it.